# Should I use ABPersonViewController or ABUnknownPersonViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, abpersonviewcontroller

I am showing the details of a person using `ABPersonViewController`. Now I have a case, where I have to show the record(details) of a person, who is not in my addressbook. I have the properties(Name/Phone number/email/address) of this person. I don't want to save this person contact in my addressbook. But I need to show the person details(display all person properties). Should I use `ABPersonViewController` or `ABUnknownPersonViewController` in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ABUnknownPersonViewController` is used to represent a partial person and has the option to disallow adding the contact to the address book.

```
ABUnknownPersonViewController *unknownPersonViewController = [[ABUnknownPersonViewController alloc] init];
unknownPersonViewController.allowsAddingToAddressBook = NO;
unknownPersonViewController.displayedPerson = person; //person is an ABRecordRef
```